# How do I stay within a for loop if certain conditions are met, before continuing to the next iteration?

Tags: python, for-loop, python-requests

I have three groups of data. I want to gather all of the data from the 3 groups. However, I can only get 100 records per request. Each group has more than 100 records. I can only tell how much data is in each group after I get the first batch of data for the group, which makes it seem like I can't use a while loop. Here's what I have.

```
def getOTCdata(weekStartDate):
    
    #set start and record limit
    start = 0
    records = 100000
    groups = ["G1", "G2", "G3"]
    
    #create for loop to get data with filters
    for tier in tier:
        params = {
            "compareFilters": [ 
                        { "compareType": "equal", "fieldName": "group", "fieldValue": group}
            ]
        }
        url = 'myURL'
        data = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(params))
        
    
        #code to download data - removed so it's not bogged down

        #check if the record total is more or less than the data remaining
        recordTotal = (data.headers)['Records']
        if start + records < recordTotal:
            start = +=100
            #I WANT TO CONTINUE IN GROUP 1
        else:
            #MOVE TO GROUP 2
```

Let's assume G1 has 150 records. I want it to run in G1 one more time. Since I will have gathered all the data in the second turn, I'll then want to move to G2. The problem is that I don't know the record total until I make the request and download the data, so I can't use a while loop right after my for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a while loop

```
 recordTotal = (data.headers)['Records']
 while start + records < recordTotal:
     start += 100
```

It will not exit out until the condition of start + records < recordTotal.

I also changed start to `start += 100` if you want the start variable to increment by 100 each time.

Comment: Will this then start the for loop over within the same group? It seems like that would just increase the start total and not go through the loop.

Comment: when it leaves the while loop after the condition has been met it will stay in the for loop it was nested in. if that for loop is G1 you can just use `break` to exit out of the for loop.

Comment: Would it reset to 0 on its own after the condition is met?